# Vim UltiSnips for python not working

Tags: vim, jedi-vim, ultisnips

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I can't figure it out. I have installed the UltiSnips plugin [UltiSnips plugin][1]. I followed all the instructions on setting it up. I added this into my .vimrc file but it's not working:

```
" Track the engine.
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'

" Snippets are separated from the engine. Add this if you want them:
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
```

I checked that  is not used anywhere in the rest of my .vimrc file. When I pritn 'cl' and press tab nothing happens. However, I am expeting it to offer me insert snippet for the python class.

This is the list of plugin I am using:

```
ctrlp
jedi-vim
SumpylFold
ultisnips
vim-airline
vim-airline-themes
vim-fugitive
Vundle
indentpython
nerdtree
vim-nerdtree-tabs
syntastic
vim-flake8
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer here [answer to my question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/vim-ultisnips-for-python-not-working). This is some clarification:

I added this line from the documentation of UltiSnips `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips"]` to the .vimrc file and it's working fine now. It wasn't obvious in my case, though.